# No se genera la notificación push android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification

Estoy tratando de mostrar una notificación push personalizada desde mi app, pero a la hora de generarla ni se esta visualizando, no me genera ningún error en el log ni nada, simplemente no la muestra, al hacer la combinación con firebase si esta recibiendo el mensaje de consola, pero aun asi no se esta mostrando nada.

Este es mi codigo para mostrar la notificación

```
public void generateNotification(String id){

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(ctx, "NOTIFI")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.background_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Titulo")
            .setContentText("TESTO")
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(ctx);

    notificationManager.notify(56, notification);

}
```

No entiendo que podria estar saliendo mal, alguien podria explicarme

Answer (score 0):

Para cada notificación el valor del id debe ser diferente, de otra forma la misma notificación se estaría sobre escribiendo y no se mostrarían las nuevas, en este caso tienes fijo como `56`  el valor del id:

```
notificationManager.notify(56, notification);
```

Como una opción puedes crear una variable

```
private int idnotification = 0;
```

este valor lo incrementarias al generar una notificación:

```
notificationManager.notify(idnotification++ , notification);
```